# Is it possible to install IIS6 instead of IIS7 on Windows Server 2012R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7, iis-6

I have to install an industrial application that claims support for Windows Server 2012R2. But when I try to install it from a clean slate Windows Server 2012R2 with IIS7, it refuses to install.

Indeed, it seems to try to detect the presence of IIS6 and fail, requesting the administrator to install IIS6 and retry to install.

So my question. Is it possible to install IIS6 instead of IIS7 on Windows Server 2012R2?

Comment: It might just be looking for iis6 management capability tools

Comment: @Drifter104: Those IIS management features are installed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I have IIS7 and IIS6 together on Win2012 R2 standard.
IIS6 is needed for SMTP by an application and it works.

Comment: Sooo... how did you get that installed then?

Answer (score -2):

In Server 2012, go to Add Roles and Features, If you have not installed the Web Server Role, be sure to select that from the Server Roles section. When you get to the Role Services page for the Web Server Role, you will have the option to select IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

Comment: If you look at the comments, you'll see the asker already did that. They don't need the management tools, they need IIS 6 itself.